# How do I access a module using a node from the command line(terminal)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to call sum() in File1.js from File2.js. But when I run File2.js nothing happens.

These are my files.

File1.js

```
export function sum(FirstItem,SecondItem){
  return (FirstItem+SecondItem)
}
```

File2.js

```
import {sum} from './File1.mjs'
console.log(sum(3,5))
```

Comment: typo? "./File1.mjs" instead of "./File1.js"

Comment: @maxm the typo is more likely where Sero wrote `File1.js`: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Answer (score 2):

use `require` and `module.exports`

> File1.js

```
module.exports = function sum(FirstItem,SecondItem){
  return (FirstItem+SecondItem)
}
```

> File2.js

```
let sum = require('./file1')
console.log(sum(3,5))
```

> output

```
8
```

**ECMAScript modules are experimental in node API.**

*In order to use them*

**Try this:**

> File1.mjs

```
export function sum(FirstItem,SecondItem){
  return (FirstItem+SecondItem)
}
```

> File2.mjs

```
import {sum} from './File1.mjs'
console.log(sum(3,5))
```

now run this using command:

```
node --experimental-modules file2.mjs
```

> Output

```
(node:12236) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
8
```

refer doc https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html.

Comment: got the following error when ran the first solution.

Error: Cannot find module /C:/Users/hopar/kj1.mjs
    at search (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:28:12)
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:64:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:58:33)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:113:40)
    at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:99:28)
    at asyncESM.loaderPromise.then (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:27)
    .....

Comment: And this when i ran the second one.
node --experimental-modules kj1.mjs
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: is this file exists `C:/Users/hopar/kj1.mjs`

Comment: Yes it does. I checked

Comment: plz provide the code which you are using to import `kj1.mjs` file.

Comment: One more thing use `module.exports = //your exported module obj` to export things from `kj1.mjs` when using `require`.

Comment: this is the code in kj1.mjs

import {sum} from './kj.mjs'
console.log(sum(3,5))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182378/discussion-between-aagam-jain-and-sero-mirzakhanyan).